# Fetch data Firebase in ngfor angular 6 not with angularFire

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular6

I am using angular6 and Firebase (npm install Firebase).
I would like to display the list of my users in a template with ngFor, here is my demarche :

ts :

```
constructor( ) {
var  users = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
        firebase.database().ref('users').on('value',(data) =>
              resolve(data.val())     
      );
    }
  });
})
```

HTML

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let user of users; let i = index">
        <td> {{user.nom}}</td>
        <td>{{user.prenom}}</td>
        <td>{{user.nom}}</td>
        <td>{{user.nom}}</td>
        <td>{{user.nom}}</td>
        <td>{{user.nom}}</td>
        <td></td>
        <td> <button (click)="onViewUser(i)" class="btn btn-primary"> 
                                        Rôle</button></td>
    </tr>     
</tbody>
```

Nothing is displayed in my tables, no error message on the console.

Comment: `users` is a `Promise` you need to resolve it by using `.then`

Comment: and use a property to store the data after resolving the Promise, you can use that property in `*ngFor`

Comment: Hello!
Sorry for the inconvenience but I do not understand too much the answer can you be clearer please ...

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things to take note of in your sample code.

You shouldn't put the logic into the `constructor` of an Angular Component. You should use lifecycle hooks, such as `ngOnInit` which fires after the component is initialised.

```js
public users;

ngOnInit() {
  firebase.auth()
    .onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        firebase.database().ref('users')
          .on('value', data => {
            this.users = data.val();
          });
      }
    });
}
```

Setting a `var` within the `constructor` doesn't make it a variable that's accessible from your view. Instead you need to use `this.users`.

It's best to wrap your table with an `ngIf` because the `ngFor` will throw an error if `users` is not defined.

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="users">
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let user of users; let i = index">
      <td>{{user.nom}}</td>
      <td>{{user.prenom}}</td>
      <td>{{user.nom}}</td>
      <td>{{user.nom}}</td>
      <td>{{user.nom}}</td>
      <td>{{user.nom}}</td>
      <td></td>
      <td> 
        <button (click)="onViewUser(i)" class="btn btn-primary">Rôle</button>
      </td>
    </tr>     
  </tbody>
</ng-template>
```

On a final note, there is a great package [`angularfire2`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2) which is a wrapper/library for Angular to integrate with Firebase. It does a lot of the heavy lifting for you and makes things a bit easier when programming an Angular project. Take a look at it, it's worth the time to use.